# OpenCV 3.2 dnn module issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, ros, yolo

i'm trying to make object detecting system using opencv but there's issue right below.

```
cae@cae-A9TB7HCGN:~$ python "/home/cae/Desktop/import cv2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cae/Desktop/import cv2.py", line 5, in <module>
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet("weights/yolov3.weights", "cfg/yolov3.cfg")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dnn'
```

how can i fix this problem?
below is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("weights/yolov3.weights", "cfg/yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

print(classes)
```

my development environment is ubuntu 18.04, ROS melodic, opencv3.2

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```py
net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel("weights/yolov3.weights", "cfg/yolov3.cfg")
```

If this does not work you should upgrade to OpenCV 3.3 or higher (I recommend at least OpenCV 4.2).